# how to read an async tcpclient network stream

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcpclient

I am trying to make a chat app using TcpClient and TcpListener using async and await in c#.

here's the code I have come up with. The problem is that once the client writes to the stream the server doesn't seem to be able to read it

```
public class asyncClient    {
   public async static Task Start()    {
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 11000);

    String message = "hello world";
    NetworkStream ns =  client.GetStream();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
    await sw.WriteLineAsync(message);



    }
public static void Main(){
    Start().Wait();
    }
}
```

and here's there listener code

```
public class AsynchListener
{
public async static Task StartListening()
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 
 11000);

    listener.Start();
    while (true) {
        TcpClient handler = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();



        NetworkStream ns = handler.GetStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
        String message = await sr.ReadLineAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("check");




}


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    StartListening().Wait();
    }

 }
```

Comment: Note that your issue has nothing at all to do with using the async API, but rather simply misusing the text-writer API incorrectly, as in the marked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the mistake, I was missing

```
await sw.FlushAsync();
```

after the writeline command